# codeigniter active record query with where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have three where conditions in my query and I want all them to merge in array only with codeigniter active record.

```
$this->db->where(array('id'=>5,'name'=>$name));  // I want to insert create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) here in this where array
```

Please dont suggest any solution like to add this condition separately.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try with `false` parameter like `$this->db->where(array(...), false);` ?

Comment: I am not sure how can i add 

create_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

within this array like 

'name'=>$name

can u please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$this->db->where(array('id'=>5,'name'=>$name))
$this->db->where('create_date >=', "DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)")
```

Comment: What if I want this both where statement in one where statement only in array ? 
Is it possible ?